# LocationManager: sometimes startUpdatingLocation don't start

Tags: ios, swift

I created an app (Swift 4.0) that, when it comes close to an iBeacon, starts the localization through `startUpdatingLocation()`.
Everything works perfectly, both with the app in the foreground, in the background and with the killed app.
But sometimes the location doesn't start.
It looks like it's never called `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`

I logged in everything: the `startUpdatingLocation` method is called and everything is configured correctly.

I tried also to use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` combined with `startUpdatingLocation()`: in this way the localization starts after the callback that, presumably, is called by `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` (in fact the first detection is triggered after more than 500 meters). But even this trick doesn't always work.

I also tried `allowDeferredLocationUpdates(untilTraveled distance: CLLocationDistance, timeout: TimeInterval)` to be able to start the localization, but nothing.

I also tried to start localization asynchronously: it didn't resolve.

I tried to use `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` both true and false: nothing.

The `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)` method is never called.

Below is the `locationManager` configuration code and the localization activation method:

```
func configureLocationService() {
  locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  locationManager?.delegate = AppDelegate.shared
  locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
  locationManager?.distanceFilter = Double(Configuration.getMinimumDistanceInMeters())

  locationManager?.activityType = .fitness

  locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

//  locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
  locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
  if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    locationManager?.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
  } else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
  }
  locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}

...

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
  if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() && CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
    manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
      manager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
        manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
        let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
        generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? There is a way to ALWAYS activate location with startUpdatingLocation()?

Comment: Hi Mateusz, were you able to resolve the issue with startUpdatingLocation failing to start the location updates sometimes in the background? I am also having the same issue, and couldn't find a solution. Highly appreciate it, if you could comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your location code is working already then the problem is somewhere else.

One common situation that causes your problem is setting up your location manager in a view controller lifecycle method like `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`. If an app starts in the background (from a cold start, not from suspended state) its view controller will never be displayed and the view lifecycle methods like `viewDidAppear` will never be called.

To debug background location problems set up your app to send a local notification at certain points (app delegate methods, view controller lifecycle methods, location manager delegate methods) and you can see what's happening in real time.

Comment: I have already used a method similar to local notification to debug (I added a `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1` in the `AppDelegate` where `startUpdatingLocation` is performed): the badge is incremented but the localization is not activated. The `locationManager` is set in the `appDelegate` in the method `application (_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

Comment: Ok, then it might be that you've set `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `true`. Does setting it to false change things?

Comment: I tried `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `true` just to try solve the problem (it was initially set to `false`)

Comment: Then I'd say try putting local notifications in several places to track what the app is doing. Find out if you're actually getting into the second `Dispatch.main` call. I'm not that great with GCD but could that nesting be causing a deadlock?